# Fluentd unable to send logs to Elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana, fluentd, efk, observability

Images being used here are:

fluent/fluentd-kubernetes-daemonset:v1-debian-elasticsearch
docker.elastic.co/elasticsearch/elasticsearch:7.5.1

Fluentd is able to place the logs in file-test.log file successfully but unable to place it in elasticsearch.

The fluent.conf file looks like this:

```
{
"elastic-fluent.conf": "<match **>
      @type elasticsearch
      host \"#{ENV['FLUENT_ELASTICSEARCH_HOST'] || 'elastic'}\"
      port \"#{ENV['FLUENT_ELASTICSEARCH_PORT'] || '9200'}\"
      scheme \"#{ENV['FLUENT_ELASTICSEARCH_SCHEME'] || 'http'}\"
      user \"#{ENV['FLUENT_ELASTICSEARCH_USER'] || 'elastic'}\"
      password \"#{ENV['FLUENT_ELASTICSEARCH_PASSWORD'] || 'Infy123'}\"
      index_name fluentd-k8s.*
      type_name fluentd
    </match>",
"file-fluent.conf": "<match **>
      @type file
      path /tmp/file-test.log
    </match>",
"fluent.conf": "@include pods-kind-fluent.conf
    #@include file-fluent.conf
    @include elastic-fluent.conf",
"pods-kind-fluent.conf": "<source>
      @type tail
      read_from_head true
      tag kubernetes.*
      path /var/log/containers/*.log
      pos_file /var/log/fluentd-containers.log.pos
      exclude_path [\"/var/log/containers/fluent*\"]
      <parse>
        @type json
        time_format %Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S.%NZ
      </parse>
    </source>
    
    <filter kubernetes.**>
      @type kubernetes_metadata
      @id filter_kube_metadata
      kubernetes_url \"#{ENV['FLUENT_FILTER_KUBERNETES_URL'] || 'https://' + ENV.fetch('KUBERNETES_SERVICE_HOST') + ':' + ENV.fetch('KUBERNETES_SERVICE_PORT') + '/api'}\"
      verify_ssl \"#{ENV['KUBERNETES_VERIFY_SSL'] || true}\"
      ca_file \"#{ENV['KUBERNETES_CA_FILE']}\"
      skip_labels \"#{ENV['FLUENT_KUBERNETES_METADATA_SKIP_LABELS'] || 'false'}\"
      skip_container_metadata \"#{ENV['FLUENT_KUBERNETES_METADATA_SKIP_CONTAINER_METADATA'] || 'false'}\"
      skip_master_url \"#{ENV['FLUENT_KUBERNETES_METADATA_SKIP_MASTER_URL'] || 'false'}\"
      skip_namespace_metadata \"#{ENV['FLUENT_KUBERNETES_METADATA_SKIP_NAMESPACE_METADATA'] || 'false'}\"
    </filter>"
```

}

The daemonset for fluentd is configured this way:

```
    kind: DaemonSet
apiVersion: apps/v1
metadata:
  name: fluentd
  namespace: logging
  uid: 30a35cb2-759e-4529-b858-61daf9913e7e
  resourceVersion: '8218652'
  generation: 13
  creationTimestamp: '2022-01-27T05:19:30Z'
  labels:
    app: fluentd
  annotations:
    deprecated.daemonset.template.generation: '13'
    kubectl.kubernetes.io/last-applied-configuration: >
      {"apiVersion":"apps/v1","kind":"DaemonSet","metadata":{"annotations":{},"labels":{"app":"fluentd"},"name":"fluentd","namespace":"logging"},"spec":{"selector":{"matchLabels":{"app":"fluentd"}},"template":{"metadata":{"labels":{"app":"fluentd"}},"spec":{"containers":[{"env":[{"name":"FLUENT_ELASTICSEARCH_HOST","value":"elastic"},{"name":"FLUENT_ELASTICSEARCH_PORT","value":"9200"},{"name":"FLUENT_ELASTICSEARCH_SCHEME","value":"http"},{"name":"FLUENTD_SYSTEMD_CONF","value":"disable"},{"name":"FLUENT_UID","value":"0"},{"name":"FLUENT_ELASTICSEARCH_USER","value":"elastic"},{"name":"FLUENT_ELASTICSEARCH_PASSWORD","value":"Infy123"}],"image":"fluent/fluentd-kubernetes-daemonset:v1-debian-elasticsearch","imagePullPolicy":"IfNotPresent","name":"fluentd","resources":{"limits":{"memory":"512Mi"},"requests":{"cpu":"100m","memory":"200Mi"}},"volumeMounts":[{"mountPath":"/var/log","name":"varlog"},{"mountPath":"/home/workspace/docker_home/containers","name":"workspacelibcontainers","readOnly":true}]}],"serviceAccount":"fluentd","serviceAccountName":"fluentd","tolerations":[{"effect":"NoSchedule","key":"node-role.kubernetes.io/master"}],"volumes":[{"hostPath":{"path":"/var/log","type":""},"name":"varlog"},{"hostPath":{"path":"/home/workspace/docker_home/containers","type":""},"name":"workspacelibcontainers"}]}}}}
  managedFields:
    - manager: kubectl-client-side-apply
      operation: Update
      apiVersion: apps/v1
      time: '2022-01-27T05:19:30Z'
      fieldsType: FieldsV1
      fieldsV1:
        f:metadata:
          f:annotations:
            .: {}
            f:deprecated.daemonset.template.generation: {}
            f:kubectl.kubernetes.io/last-applied-configuration: {}
          f:labels:
            .: {}
            f:app: {}
        f:spec:
          f:revisionHistoryLimit: {}
          f:selector: {}
          f:template:
            f:metadata:
              f:labels:
                .: {}
                f:app: {}
            f:spec:
              f:containers:
                k:{"name":"fluentd"}:
                  .: {}
                  f:env:
                    .: {}
                    k:{"name":"FLUENTD_SYSTEMD_CONF"}:
                      .: {}
                      f:name: {}
                      f:value: {}
                    k:{"name":"FLUENT_ELASTICSEARCH_HOST"}:
                      .: {}
                      f:name: {}
                      f:value: {}
                    k:{"name":"FLUENT_ELASTICSEARCH_PASSWORD"}:
                      .: {}
                      f:name: {}
                      f:value: {}
                    k:{"name":"FLUENT_ELASTICSEARCH_PORT"}:
                      .: {}
                      f:name: {}
                      f:value: {}
                    k:{"name":"FLUENT_ELASTICSEARCH_SCHEME"}:
                      .: {}
                      f:name: {}
                      f:value: {}
                    k:{"name":"FLUENT_ELASTICSEARCH_USER"}:
                      .: {}
                      f:name: {}
                      f:value: {}
                    k:{"name":"FLUENT_UID"}:
                      .: {}
                      f:name: {}
                      f:value: {}
                  f:image: {}
                  f:imagePullPolicy: {}
                  f:name: {}
                  f:resources:
                    .: {}
                    f:limits:
                      .: {}
                      f:memory: {}
                    f:requests:
                      .: {}
                      f:cpu: {}
                      f:memory: {}
                  f:terminationMessagePath: {}
                  f:terminationMessagePolicy: {}
                  f:volumeMounts:
                    .: {}
                    k:{"mountPath":"/var/log"}:
                      .: {}
                      f:mountPath: {}
                      f:name: {}
              f:dnsPolicy: {}
              f:restartPolicy: {}
              f:schedulerName: {}
              f:securityContext: {}
              f:serviceAccount: {}
              f:serviceAccountName: {}
              f:terminationGracePeriodSeconds: {}
              f:tolerations: {}
              f:volumes:
                .: {}
                k:{"name":"varlog"}:
                  .: {}
                  f:hostPath:
                    .: {}
                    f:type: {}
                  f:name: {}
          f:updateStrategy:
            f:rollingUpdate:
              .: {}
              f:maxSurge: {}
              f:maxUnavailable: {}
            f:type: {}
    - manager: kubectl-edit
      operation: Update
      apiVersion: apps/v1
      time: '2022-03-03T11:08:03Z'
      fieldsType: FieldsV1
      fieldsV1:
        f:spec:
          f:template:
            f:spec:
              f:containers:
                k:{"name":"fluentd"}:
                  f:volumeMounts:
                    k:{"mountPath":"/home/workspace/docker_home"}:
                      .: {}
                      f:mountPath: {}
                      f:name: {}
                      f:readOnly: {}
              f:volumes:
                k:{"name":"varlibdockercontainers"}:
                  .: {}
                  f:hostPath:
                    .: {}
                    f:path: {}
                    f:type: {}
                  f:name: {}
    - manager: dashboard
      operation: Update
      apiVersion: apps/v1
      time: '2022-03-03T12:31:28Z'
      fieldsType: FieldsV1
      fieldsV1:
        f:spec:
          f:template:
            f:spec:
              f:containers:
                k:{"name":"fluentd"}:
                  f:volumeMounts:
                    k:{"mountPath":"/fluentd/etc"}:
                      .: {}
                      f:mountPath: {}
                      f:name: {}
                      f:readOnly: {}
                    k:{"mountPath":"/var/log"}:
                      .: {}
                      f:mountPath: {}
                      f:name: {}
                    k:{"mountPath":"/var/log/containers"}:
                      .: {}
                      f:mountPath: {}
                      f:name: {}
                      f:readOnly: {}
              f:volumes:
                k:{"name":"config"}:
                  .: {}
                  f:configMap:
                    .: {}
                    f:defaultMode: {}
                    f:name: {}
                  f:name: {}
                k:{"name":"varlog"}:
                  f:hostPath:
                    f:path: {}
                k:{"name":"workspacelibcontainers"}:
                  .: {}
                  f:hostPath:
                    .: {}
                    f:path: {}
                    f:type: {}
                  f:name: {}
    - manager: kube-controller-manager
      operation: Update
      apiVersion: apps/v1
      time: '2022-03-03T13:12:00Z'
      fieldsType: FieldsV1
      fieldsV1:
        f:status:
          f:currentNumberScheduled: {}
          f:desiredNumberScheduled: {}
          f:numberAvailable: {}
          f:numberMisscheduled: {}
          f:numberReady: {}
          f:observedGeneration: {}
          f:updatedNumberScheduled: {}
spec:
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: fluentd
  template:
    metadata:
      creationTimestamp: null
      labels:
        app: fluentd
    spec:
      volumes:
        - name: workspacelibcontainers
          hostPath:
            path: /var/log/containers
            type: ''
        - name: varlog
          hostPath:
            path: /var/log
            type: ''
        - name: config
          configMap:
            name: fluentd
            defaultMode: 420
        - name: varlibdockercontainers
          hostPath:
            path: /home/workspace/docker_home
            type: ''
      containers:
        - name: fluentd
          image: fluent/fluentd-kubernetes-daemonset:v1-debian-elasticsearch
          env:
            - name: FLUENT_ELASTICSEARCH_HOST
              value: elastic
            - name: FLUENT_ELASTICSEARCH_PORT
              value: '9200'
            - name: FLUENT_ELASTICSEARCH_SCHEME
              value: http
            - name: FLUENTD_SYSTEMD_CONF
              value: disable
            - name: FLUENT_UID
              value: '0'
            - name: FLUENT_ELASTICSEARCH_USER
              value: elastic
            - name: FLUENT_ELASTICSEARCH_PASSWORD
              value: Infy123
          resources:
            limits:
              memory: 512Mi
            requests:
              cpu: 100m
              memory: 200Mi
          volumeMounts:
            - name: varlog
              mountPath: /var/log
            - name: workspacelibcontainers
              readOnly: true
              mountPath: /var/log/containers
            - name: config
              readOnly: true
              mountPath: /fluentd/etc
            - name: varlibdockercontainers
              readOnly: true
              mountPath: /home/workspace/docker_home
          terminationMessagePath: /dev/termination-log
          terminationMessagePolicy: File
          imagePullPolicy: IfNotPresent
      restartPolicy: Always
      terminationGracePeriodSeconds: 30
      dnsPolicy: ClusterFirst
      serviceAccountName: fluentd
      serviceAccount: fluentd
      securityContext: {}
      schedulerName: default-scheduler
      tolerations:
        - key: node-role.kubernetes.io/master
          effect: NoSchedule
  updateStrategy:
    type: RollingUpdate
    rollingUpdate:
      maxUnavailable: 1
      maxSurge: 0
  revisionHistoryLimit: 10
status:
  currentNumberScheduled: 5
  numberMisscheduled: 0
  desiredNumberScheduled: 5
  numberReady: 5
  observedGeneration: 13
  updatedNumberScheduled: 5
  numberAvailable: 5
```

Comment: The file config is commented i.e. `#@include file-fluent.conf`. With only `@include elastic-fluent.conf`, you're not able to see the logs, right? Have you tried to configure its `buffer` options? What is your use case? Do you want to push logs both to file and es? Or, file is there just for testing?

Comment: The file is just for testing also its working fine , coming to the usecase I need to push logs from a lot of banking components into the es. Do you notice any mistake ?

Comment: Right. It's fine with that commented line. For es, you need to configure and test the `buffer` options e.g. `flush_mode immediate`. https://github.com/uken/fluent-plugin-elasticsearch#buffer-options

Comment: Buffer flushing parameters: https://docs.fluentd.org/configuration/buffer-section#flushing-parameters